# Video.js format .mpd .m3u8 not supported and depreciation messages

Tags: javascript, css, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to use video.js and I saw the below console messages.

1. Why would CSS not load before html?
2. How do I fix the `onmozfullscreenchange` and `onmozfullscreenerror` depreciation message?
3. I thought dash was support with video.js, why is `Specified “type” attribute of “application/dash+xml” is not supported.`
4. Same error as (3) with specified type of `“application/x-mpegURL”` format?

Basically, how do I fix all these messages?  I took the code from https://videojs.com/getting-started/.  However, I added the `vjs-fill vjs-big-play-centered` classes

HTML CODE

```
<head>
 
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video
    id="my-video"
    class="video-js vjs-fill vjs-big-play-centered"
    controls
    preload="auto"

    poster="explainer-video-2-poster.png"
    data-setup="{}"
  >
    <source src="https://videodelivery.net/videoid/manifest/video.mpd" type="application/dash+xml" />
    <source src="https://videodelivery.net/videoid/manifest/video.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL" />
    <p class="vjs-no-js">
      To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
      web browser that
      <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
        >supports HTML5 video</a
      >
    </p>
  </video>

  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.8.4/video.js"></script>
</body>
```

Console Error:

> ```
> > Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are
> > not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.
> > videojs-ie8.min.js:1:9637 onmozfullscreenchange is deprecated.
> > videojs-ie8.min.js:1:9637 onmozfullscreenerror is deprecated.
> > videojs-ie8.min.js:1:9637 Specified “type” attribute of
> > “application/dash+xml” is not supported. Load of media resource
> > https://videodelivery.net/videoid/manifest/video.mpd failed. Trying to
> > load from next <source> element. video-js.html Specified “type”
> > attribute of “application/x-mpegURL” is not supported. Load of media
> > resource https://videodelivery.net/videoid/manifest/video.m3u8 failed.
> > video-js.html All candidate resources failed to load. Media load
> > paused. video-js.html The character encoding of the HTML document was
> > not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some
> > browser configurations if the document contains characters from
> > outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be
> > declared in the document or in the transfer protocol. video-js.html
> > All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
> ```